# TikZ: calc and use a product of n number

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I have a code to calc a product of n numbers with `pgfmath` and `foreach` as a macro `\Prod`.

But if I say `\pgfmathtsetmacro\N{1+\Prod}` I get an error.

What do I have to do?

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\pgfmathsetglobalmacro#1#2{%
  \pgfmathparse{#2}%
  \global\let#1\pgfmathresult}
\def\List{1}

\newcommand\Prod{%
\def\Product{1}%
\foreach \i in \List {%  
\pgfmathsetglobalmacro{\Product}{int(\Product * \i)}}%
\Product}

\begin{document}
\section*{works}
\def\List{1,2,3,1,-1}
Product of {\List} is \Prod

\section*{works}
\def\List{2,2,3}
Product of {\List} is \Prod

\section*{works not}
%\pgfmathtsetmacro\N{1+\Prod}
%\N
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\Prod` is a macro which, when complete, defines `\Product`.  Therefore, use `\Product` in the definition of `\N`,not `\Prod`.

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\pgfmathsetglobalmacro#1#2{%
  \pgfmathparse{#2}%
  \global\let#1\pgfmathresult}
\def\List{1}

\newcommand\Prod{%
\def\Product{1}%
\foreach \i in \List {%  
\pgfmathsetglobalmacro{\Product}{int(\Product * \i)}}%
\Product}

\begin{document}
\section*{works}
\def\List{1,2,3,1,-1}
Product of {\List} is \Prod

\section*{works}
\def\List{2,2,3}
Product of {\List} is \Prod

\section*{works not}
\pgfmathsetmacro\N{1+\Product}
\N
\end{document}
```

[image]